# SQL: KeyError when trying to insert data into has relation

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

We are working with a given movie database.
This relational schema is given:

movie(budget, homepage, id, keywords, original_language, original_title, overview, popularity, production_companies, production_countries, release_data, revenue, runtime, spoken_languages, status, tagline, title, vote_average, vote_count, cast, crew)
pk(id)

has(mid, gid)
pk(mid, gid)
fk(mid) refs. movie(id)
fk(gid) refs. genre(id)

genre(id, name)
pk(id)

This code for creating a table and inserting data for 'genre' is given:

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE genre(                
id integer,               
name text,                
primary key(id)    
)""")
```

---

```
for movie_genres in data['genres']:        
    for genres in movie_genres:    
        try:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO genre VALUES (:id, :name)", {'id': genres['id'], 'name': genres['name']})

        except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:

            pass # ignore SQLite complaints about UNIQUE primary keys
```

How do I create a table and insert data for the has relation? I tried doing it the same way but I keep on getting KeyError: has

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely that multiple movies have the same genre, thus you want to IGNORE attempts to add the same referenced genre. As such try :-

```
c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO genre VALUES (:id, :name)", {'id': genres['id'], 'name': genres['name']})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Doing this gives me the same error. Inserting data into genre works. The problem the program has is with HAS1 (when I try to insert data into this table)..

Comment: @FaridaMesqi you won't be able to insert into the has table if either the genre or the movie doesn't exist. Thus inserting into the has table should follow the insert for the movie and the insert for the genre that is referenced by the row being inserted into the has table, that is unless you turn off FK support. [SQLite Foreign Key Support](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Comment: I created a table for movie, but how do I insert data here? I have to do it the same way as I did with genre (movie data already exists). But I dont know how because for genre you just did movie_genre and data['genres'], but how to do this for movie itself? Genres is also in the movie data file, thats why you can access the genre data that way.